# Is there a way to specify a default download path for Google Drive/Chrome to an external microSD card?

Tags: external-sd, chrome-for-android, downloading, google-drive

I have a 512 GB external microSD card that's connected to a smart phone.

For speed reasons, I would like some functions like the camera to still use the on-board phone memory, but would like files downloaded from Google Chrome and Google Drive to go to the external microSD card by default.

Is there any way to do that?

I tried the following on an per-app basis:

- **(1) Google Chrome -> Settings -> Downloads -> Download locations** //
  But it says the SD Card does not have enough space, despite having 100's of GB of space that I can still transfer to after any download to the phone's memory
- **(2) Google Drive -> Settings** // But there's no option to change the default download path there.